# How to get AppID of my application to access application data folder in iOS simulator?

Tags: ios, sh, calabash-ios

I am building `Cucumber/Calabash` tests for my iOS app. I need to access my application data folder in simulator, to copy data to that folder.
I can get to this path:

```
~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/[DeviceID]/data/Containers/Data/Application/[NEED TO GET THIS AppID]
```

But I need to detect my `[AppID]` to access the right folder. Is there any method to get it from application name or bundle id via terminal or using some `.sh` scripts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this with using script like this:

```
APPLICATION_DATA_FOLDER = $1
cd APPLICATION_DATA_FOLDER

for dir in *
do
 IDENTIFIER=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "print :MCMMetadataIdentifier" ${dir}/.com.apple.mobile_container_manager.metadata.plist)
 if [ "${IDENTIFIER}" == "YOUR APPNAME HERE" ]; then
  cd -
  echo "${APPLICATION_DATA_FOLDER}/${dir}"
  exit 0
 fi
done
```

I am passing application data folder as path - this:

```
~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/[DeviceID]/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/
```

The script goes through the `.plist` files in folders and tries to match my Application name

Answer (score 2):

In Swift 4, insert the following code inside `viewDidLoad()`:

```
    let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true) // get the Documents folder path
    
    let pathForDocumentDir = documentsPath[0]
    print("pathForDocumentDir: \(pathForDocumentDir)")
```

e.g.:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true) // get the Documents folder path
        
        let pathForDocumentDir = documentsPath[0]
        print("pathForDocumentDir: \(pathForDocumentDir)")
    }
}
```

This will print something like this in the Console output:

```
/Users/user/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/11321A31-27D6-49E0-85C8-D7EDEFA6751F/data/Containers/Data/Application/BB9EAD09-17B5-4FA1-907A-0EDFC07BFA62/Documents
```

Code based on [this source](https://slicode.com/how-to-get-simulator-app-and-transfer-to-other-simulator-running-on-different-mac/)

Answer (score 1):

[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] will give you the top folder of your application.
It will look something like this:

~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/[DeviceID]/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/[AppID]/[AppName.app]

Then you can get [AppID] using an NSArray:

```
NSArray *components = [path componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
NSLog(@"AppID: %@", [components objectAtIndex:[components count] - 2]);
```

Comment: I have to access this via terminal comands... (used in .rb files of calabash tests) also my application is made with C# and Xamarin not in objective C or swift...
I can get AppID in Containers/**Bundle**/Application/, via searching BundleName but that ID is different from AppID in Containers/**Data**/Application...

Answer (score 0):

I do it in 2 steps:

1. Find OR add(save on simulator) some unique file. In my case it's file with .xlsx extension.
2. Use script that can be run in terminal:

   cd ~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/[DeviceId] && find . -name '*.xlsx'

It returns path of found files where u can get appropriate application Id by using Regex for example:

```
./data/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/5BBE0D19-83A3-41D5-81DA-971CB547B9D0/File Provider Storage/test_pdf_file1578673688647.xlsx
```